# Is it possible to manually line break on a specific attribute when using XmlWriter in Indent mode?

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

`XmlWriter` allows configuring indentation when using `XmlWriter.Create` and `XmlWriterSettings`.

In general, I want `Indent = true` and `NewLineOnAttributes = false`, *except* when writing `xmlns` namespace declarations at the beginning of the file, where I would like to have new lines between each `xmlns` namespace for readability.

Is it possible to force `XmlWriter` to do a line break after writing a specific attribute, and otherwise follow general indentation rules?

I tried using `WriteWhitespace` and `WriteRaw` with `\n`:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlWriterIndent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var output = new StringBuilder();
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = true }))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Node");

                writer.WriteAttributeString("key1", "value1");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("key2", "value2");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "n1", null, "scheme://mynamespace.com");
                writer.WriteRaw("\n");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "n2", null, "scheme://anothernamespace.com");

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }

            var xml = output.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this throws an exception saying the XML document would be invalid.

**UPDATE:** Actually, after checking more carefully, the exception is not in the `WriteRaw` method itself, but rather in the following `WriteAttributeString` call, as I am calling these methods in a loop for all namespaces.

It looks like `WriteRaw` moves the `XmlWriter` into the element content state somehow. Is it possible to use `WriteRaw` or somehow insert whitespace between attributes without changing the writer state?

**UPDATE:** Added self-contained example. Actually, it looks like in general namespace declarations are ignored even when using `NewLineOnAttributes`, i.e. all attributes have new lines *except* namespace declarations, which are somehow handled differently despite being regular attributes.

Unfortunately, I'm approaching the conclusion that the `XmlWriter` API is simply broken, as there is no way to do raw formatting of XML, since the `WriteRaw` forces a change in the writer state.

Looking into the actual source code at referencesource shows that the special write method `WriteIndent` is used to handle indentation inside `XmlWriter`. This method has special behavior that doesn't change the state, but there seems to be no way to access it or the underlying data stream, so it seems impossible to work around this without a full reimplementation of the entire XML writer stack:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.cs,1739

Comment: Can you enable `NewLineOnAttributes` only during the time you write the element/attribute with the XML namespace?

Comment: Set NewLineOnAttributes = false after you write the namespaces.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to change `XmlWriterSettings` properties after the `XmlWriter` has been created. For some reason they are marked read-only, and the framework will throw an exception if you try to change anything.

Comment: @glopes Please edit your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Include all the attempts you have done to add the new line inside the XML element and add the error messages and results you got from them. Specially include the full exception message to your attempts.

Comment: I have added the minimal reproducible example and further insights into the API and observed behavior. I don't think the exception message will add any further information, and in any case whoever wants to see it just needs to run the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XmlWriter` API has no way to do raw formatting of XML attributes. `WriteRaw` would be the appropriate method to call, but the internal `XmlWellFormedWriter` returned by `XmlWriter.Create` always advances the writer state when this method is called, advancing the XML state machine to content. If we are in the middle of writing attributes, this finishes the start tag of the element and moves to content, which is *not* where we want to write our custom indentation.

Several internal `XmlWriter` classes implement more low-level `WriteRaw` methods, but there seems to be no way of accessing them, as `XmlWriter.Create` always wraps created writers with a `XmlWellFormedWriter` instance before returning.

Therefore, the only way to workaround the issue is to define and instantiate a custom `XmlWriter` class which controls *both* the underlying stream *and* the base `XmlWriter`. That way we can bypass the `XmlWriter` API and write directly into the stream when we need to do our custom indentation.

There are a couple of limitations with the current solution:

1. `XmlWriter` implementations do not write directly to the stream, and instead keep their own internal buffers for efficiency. That means that whenever we want to bypass the `XmlWriter` we need to call `Flush` to make sure that our stream is in the right position;
2. In order for indentation to make sense, we need to keep track of the correct indent level. To do this for the whole document would be possible, but tedious. For simplicity, this solution only formats the top level `xmlns` declarations;
3. For completeness, we need to deal with both `Stream` and `TextWriter` as possible output types.

Finally, the `XmlWriter` abstract class has dozens of methods to override which we don't care about, but that need to be bridged to the underlying writer. For conciseness, I have omitted all but the relevant overrides:

```
class XmlnsIndentedWriter : XmlWriter
{
    bool isRootElement;
    int indentLevel = -1;
    readonly Stream stream;
    readonly TextWriter textWriter;
    readonly XmlWriter writer;

    private XmlnsIndentedWriter(Stream output, XmlWriter baseWriter)
    {
        stream = output;
        writer = baseWriter;
    }

    private XmlnsIndentedWriter(TextWriter output, XmlWriter baseWriter)
    {
        textWriter = output;
        writer = baseWriter;
    }

    public static new XmlWriter Create(StringBuilder output, XmlWriterSettings settings)
    {
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings);
        return new XmlnsIndentedWriter(new StringWriter(output, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), writer);
    }

    public static new XmlWriter Create(Stream stream, XmlWriterSettings settings)
    {
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);
        return new XmlnsIndentedWriter(stream, writer);
    }

    // snip: override all methods in the XmlWriter class

    private void WriteRawText(string text)
    {
        writer.Flush();
        if (stream != null)
        {
            // example only, this could be optimized with buffers, etc.
            var buf = writer.Settings.Encoding.GetBytes(text);
            stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }
        else if (textWriter != null)
        {
            textWriter.Write(text);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
        isRootElement = true;
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if (isRootElement)
        {
            if (indentLevel < 0)
            {
                // initialize the indent level;
                // length of local name + any control characters / prefixes, etc. 
                indentLevel = localName.Length + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // do not track indent for the whole document;
                // when second element starts, we are done
                isRootElement = false;
                indentLevel = -1;
            }
        }
        writer.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();
        if (indentLevel >= 0)
        {
            RawText(Environment.NewLine + new string(' ', indentLevel));
        }
    }
}
```

There is a choice to add the indentation either before each attribute, or after.

Here I have opted for the latter, as it seems to be the only option if you want to also indent the default `xmlns` declaration. This declaration is written out after the writer state moves to content, and there seems to be no way of intercepting it otherwise.